# Git on Cygwin: Fails to add the host to the list of known hosts

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I'm using cygwin git on windows 7 and everytime I do any operation that requires communication with github via SSH, I get the following message:

```
Could not create directory '/home/ltb/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

So far so good, I understand what's going on above. But once I enter yes, SSH should be able to insert the github key in the `known_hosts` file and move. Instead I get the following error message everytime:

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/ltb/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: mkdir -p /home/ltb/.ssh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](https://thestandardoutput.com/2013/05/some-notes-on-using-git-with-cygwin-on-windows/) about this very problem. The solution lies in the fact that your home folder in cygwin is most likely under `/cygdrive/c/home/ltb/` and NOT under `/home/ltb/` as you listed above. You can fix it like this:

1. Locate the passwd file, which is usually at C:\cygwin\etc\
2. Open it with your prefered editor
3. On the line that starts with your username, change the section that reads `/home/<user>` to read `/cygdrive/c/home/<user>` where `<user>` is your cygwin username. Adjust this path accordingly if different.
4. Save the changes and restart the Cygwin Terminal

Hope this helps...

Comment: For newer Cygwin you need to edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` instead and add `db_home: windows` then restart Cygwin.  See [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1026123/333230).